# Proper Nav Menu Method?

Tags: html, css

All of the css nav menu tutorial I found are using float:left to align the menus to the left side of a web page, so when I try to use float:right in order to right-align the menus, the menus' positions reversed, for example:

```
The original menu (left-floated):
|Food | For | Life

The menu that I wanted to right-align (right-floated):  
|Life | For | Food
```

So, what is the proper way to create the nav menu without the menu resulting in being reversed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse their order in the HTML.

Or float the `<ul>` container to the right and the `<li>` menu items to the left within it.

Answer (score 0):

use only float:left,right in the `<ul>`....with display inline in `<li>` that will work smoothly...
& for further details see the example : http://jsfiddle.net/uM6CM/

Answer (score 0):

1. Use text-align: right; to your Nav or UL
2. Set display inline-block; to your li.
3. Not use float.
4. For IE6 and IE7 display inline-block will not work you can use display: inline and zoom: 1 for IE6 and IE7 only.